# Is there a working extension to import Kinect skeleton data as animation into Blender?

Tags: animation, add-on, conversion

I already tried [Bloop](http://dm.tzi.de/bloop/) which would end in rewrite lots of C++ and Phyton code. The issues with bloop are described [here im-so-annoyed-im-resurrecting-this-blog](http://www.just-another-right-wing-rant.blogspot.de/2012/07/im-so-annoyed-im-resurrecting-this-blog.html).

For other things like [RGBDemo](http://labs.manctl.com/rgbdemo/index.php/Main/Download) the dependencies to OpenNI are no longer available.

It wouldn't be necessary that the import is done in real-time.

Is there any working module/add-on, external converter?

Comment: Have you looked into http://www.ni-mate.com? They have a live kinect-to-blender plugin.

Comment: @MikePan Thank you so much I didn't notice ni-mate, can't wait to try it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should be a script for importing bvh files under

File -> import -> Motion Capture (.bvh)

, at least in current versions of blender.

A program to save kinect skeleton data as a .bvh file can be found e.g. on  the following site:
http://tech.integrate.biz/kinect_mocap.htm

Comment: After uninstalling the Kinect SDK (which conficlts with the OpenNI stack) and installing everything from http://tech.integrate.biz/openni.htm I still get the error: kinect10.dll cannot be found.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the existing import function for .bvh files. Thanks

Comment: After uninstalling everything and install OpenNI stack followed by Kinect SDK 1.0 (old) I was able to start BVH Motion Capture. But as soon I start recording it terminates (Caught AccessViolationException in OpenNI.dll).

Comment: The kinect drivers & openNi can be problematic to install, I would recommend 'brekel kinect auto installer' available at http://www.brekel.com/ under "Brekel Kinect (free)" -> "download".

Comment: I just found that software, currently installing, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @sarahm I tried [Brekel Kinect](http://www.brekel.com/?page_id=170) and it worked with the following settings:

[image]

The results weren't as good as I hoped: The sceleton jitters, bones are sometimes crossed.

Comment: Kinect and similar gaming devices are designed to recognise motion more than record it, it's very limited for motion capture.