# Blender track quadruped with kinect?

Tags: animation, bones, tracking

Can blender handle quadruped track data from a kinect?

Comment: Is this a question about features of kinect tracking or whether blender can use the data? What method are you currently using to import the kinect data?

Comment: @RayMairlot - I don't have the kinect yet, I wanted to find out if it's possible before I go rent or buy one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a Kinect's tracking features.

Comment: @RayMairlot - Its asking about the features within blender. If blender can import and use data from a quadruped .

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/540/is-there-a-working-extension-to-import-kinect-skeleton-data-as-animation-into-bl

Comment: That was what I was trying to ascertain from my question. If you can edit your question to make it clear you are asking specifically about whether blender can handle quadruped data the question can be reopened. Currently, the main point in your question seems to be "are kinects only designed to track bipeds like humans?", which is not about blender.

Comment: @RayMairlot - Hows this

Comment: Nominated for reopening.

Comment: I will say that it should be able to, depending on the tool you used for the import